# Dequeue whole queue

Tags: c#

How can I dequeue all values in a Queue? In the following code when I try to do so loop stops in the middle. I don't understand.

```
Queue<int> integers = new Queue<int>();

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    integers.Enqueue(i);
}

Console.WriteLine(integers.Count); // 20
Console.WriteLine();

for (int i = 0; i < integers.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(integers.Dequeue()); // Stops at 10
}

Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine(integers.Count); // 10
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? See that the count value decreases. Use `while (integers.Count > 0)` or `int count = integers.Count; for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)`. This should help

Answer (score 10):

Your `integers.Count` is decreasing every time you dequeue, so after ten iterations of your `for` loop, it will be at 10, so the loop will exit.
For your code to work, just save the length of your queue before the loop, like so:

```
var length = integers.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(integers.Dequeue());
}
```

*edit:* Above solution is with minimal changes to OP's code. As per suggestions in the comments (and other answers), a `while` loop is generally more recommended for this type of task:

```
while (integers.Count != 0) {
    Console.WriteLine(integers.Dequeue());
}
```

Comment: Or change loop to _"while (integers.Count != 0)"_

Comment: If a queue item gets added from the loop, you will have the same problem... change loop to "while (integers.Count != 0)" is the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

Just change the loop to be:

```
while(integers.Count > 0) { Console.WriteLine(integers.Dequeue()); }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are removing items from queue when you dequeue.

Try this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/FbXgoA

```
Queue<int> integers = new Queue<int>();

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    integers.Enqueue(i);
}

Console.WriteLine(integers.Count); // 20
Console.WriteLine();

while(integers.Count > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine(integers.Count + ": " + integers.Dequeue());
}

Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine(integers.Count); // 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that as you dequeue the integers, integers.Count is also updated at the same time.

Thus, by the middle of the queue, i = 10 and also integers.Count = 10, so the for loop exits.

Try this:

```
while (integers.Count > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine(integers.Dequeue());
}
```